# I want to remove recursively square brackets from file names

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a lot of files in a directory containing square brackets for example:

```
Filename 1 [12454365].txt
```

I tried the following script but it's giving me the an error.

```
get-childitem -recurse | foreach { move-item -literalpath $_.name ($_.name -replace '\[.*\]', '')}
```

Error message

```
move-item : A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

Only want to remove square brackets not everything in between!

Comment: Try adding `-whatif` switch to `move-item`. That'll show you what the move operation is about to do, so watch for any weirdness in file names/paths.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue: `Set-Content -LiteralPath '.\1 [1234567].txt' -Value 'test' ; Get-ChildItem  -Recurse | foreach { move-item -literalpath $_.name ($_.name -replace '\[.*\]', '')} `  Are these files on a USB device? Would removing the square brackets and everything in between create duplicate or invalid file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are replacing the brackets and everything in between.

```
Get-ChildItem * -Filter "*`[*`]*" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '\[','' -replace '\]','' }
```

Comment: this did the trick for me! I forgot to mention that I only want to remove the square brackets not everything in between. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify `-Recurse`, you will need to specify the file with `FullName` because it will be targeted other than the current directory.

```
(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse) | foreach {
    $dest = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($_.Name -replace "[\[\]]")
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName $dest
}
```

Also, it is better to use `Rename-Item` for file renaming.

```
(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse) | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "[\[\]]" }
```